# Return Boolean for document id existance in firebase without auth

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

My requests on firebase are limited to authenticated users until yet.

Now i would like to check if a document with a given id exists in the firestore db without being authenticated and i don't want to make my whole document tree readable by directly allowing by standard security rules.
The only thing I need is a yes or no for existance.

Is maybe the "exists" security rule the best way to achieve this or is there a best practice for this case out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing is possible by [using granular operations](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-structure#granular_operations) in your security rules. The key concept here is that a `read` rule can be broken down into `get` (for reading a specific document) and `list` operations (for collection-wide reads and queries).

In most default rules you'll find an operation like this for reads:

```
match /yourCollection/{doc} {
  allow read: if <condition>;
```

This allows any user to read **or query** the entire collection, as long as they match the condition.

If you only want the user to be able to read a specific document, you can use `get` instead of read:

```
match /yourCollection/{doc} {
  allow get : if <condition>;
```

Now any queries to or read of the entire collection are automatically rejected, and only single-document read operations are allowed - and even then only when they meet the condition.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a HTTPS-triggered Cloud Function which only serves this single one purpose. Then it is possible to check for the existence of a document, without tearing down security measures; even if guessing the name, there still is little risk involved, when the response is just true or false.

Comment: although I user granular operations as a solution Cloud functions could be the better option depending on the use case